# encrypt y decrypt laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-6

T¿engo un problema para desencriptar un dato que me llega de base de datos, cuando lo almaceno lo hago de la siguiente manera:

```html
$pwd = Crypt::encrypt($password);
```

Para desencriptrarlo realizo lo siguiente:

```html
$decrypted = Crypt::decrypt($client->password_client);
```

Pero cuando ejecuto la función me salta este error:

DecryptException
The payload is invalid.

Que he hecho mal?

Gracias

Comment: Es un riesgo de seguridad encriptar el password para luego desencriptarlo, si tu puedes hacerlo, cualquiera con acceso al código podría. Lo que normalmente se hace es crear un [`hash`](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Funci%C3%B3n_hash) a partir del `password` recibido. Luego, cada vez que alguien hace login, se calcula el `hash` del `password` introducido y se compara con el almacenado en DB. Saludos

Comment: He intentado de todo, con hash, pero al momento de validar siembre me arroja false --- if(Hash::check($password, $client->password))

Comment: ¿Qué versión de Laravel usas? Veo que has colocado la etiqueta [laravel-5].

Comment: Ya lo he resuelto, resulta que la persona que creó el modelo colocó el campo en la base de datos con una longitud de 45 caracteres, el hash que se genera es superior, por lo tanto cuando se almacenaba la contraseña, se almacenaba el hash incompleto

Comment: Recalco la recomendación de Mauricio, es más seguro utilizar Hash, gracias por el aporte

Comment: Ok, igual te sugiero que las contraseñas las almacenes como Hash y no como dato encriptado. Saludos